# Import Blender Hair Alembic File into Unity Strand-Based Hair

Tags: particles, hair, unity

Has anyone successfully used Blender with the [Unity strand-based Hair Solution](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.demoteam.hair)?

In Blender I made my hair with partical system and exported as alembic file. But in Unity, *Hair Asset* doesn't recognize the alembic file, even if I drag and drop the file directly into the panel it doesn't show in the scene and the following error shows up:

```
Discarding provided curve set due to incomplete (out of bounds) vertex data.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetBuilder:BuildStrandGroupResolved (Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset/StrandGroup&,Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset&,Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset/SettingsResolve&,Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetProvisional/CurveSet&) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.demoteam.hair@5c82062006/Editor/HairAssetBuilder.cs:306)
Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetBuilder:BuildStrandGroupAlembic (Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset/StrandGroup&,Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset&,UnityEngine.Formats.Alembic.Importer.AlembicCurves[],int&) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.demoteam.hair@5c82062006/Editor/HairAssetBuilder.cs:684)
Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetBuilder:BuildHairAssetAlembic (Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.demoteam.hair@5c82062006/Editor/HairAssetBuilder.cs:204)
Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetBuilder:BuildHairAsset (Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAsset,Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetBuilder/BuildFlags) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.demoteam.hair@5c82062006/Editor/HairAssetBuilder.cs:91)
Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetEditor:DrawImporterGUI () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.demoteam.hair@5c82062006/Editor/HairAssetEditor.cs:404)
Unity.DemoTeam.Hair.HairAssetEditor:OnInspectorGUI () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.demoteam.hair@5c82062006/Editor/HairAssetEditor.cs:131)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Blender version: 3.2, 3.3, 3.4
Unity Version: 2022.1.23f1 HDRP
Unity Alembic Package Version 2.3.0
Unity Hair System 0.9.1-exp.1

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for this, yes you just need to install the Alembic package in Unity first, and set the Hair asset to use Alembic, not Procedural.